# C++, Qt, как правильно применять функции драйвера (dll)?

Tags: c++, qt, dll, com, драйвер

Имеется драйвер для работы с устройством через COM-port (драйвер работоспособен и тесты пашут) с именем "MifareDrv.dll" и именем объекта AddIn.MifareDrv . К слову даже есть пример подключения драйвера на делфи через OleControl:

```
uses MifareLib_TLB;
var
Driver: TMifareDrv;
begin
Driver := TMifareDrv.Create(nil);
Driver.Beep;
end;
```

(есть даже на 1С, но я думаю он тут не нужен) 
При реализации на Qt пошел через QLibrary. метод load подтверждает, что драйвер загружается. 
Потом я решил проверить одну из функций следующим образом.

```
  typedef void (*Connect) (); 
  Connect con = (Connect)mylib.resolve ("Beep");
  con ();
```

и выполняться такое дело не хочет (компилируется, но на выполнение падает); и так с любыми функциями. 
Собственно вопрос: так как правильно реализовать работу с функциями драйвера? В чем я не прав? Какие еще можно применить способы?

UPD:Версия под Visual C++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include "Objbase.h"
#import "MifareDrv.tlb" rename_namespace("mifare") // с dll тоже должно работать
CLSID clsid;
mifare::IMifareDrv ;
IDispatch *pWApp;
mifare::IMifareDrv *pMiDrv;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromProgID(L"Addin.MifareDrv", &clsid);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        LPOLESTR tmpbuf;
        StringFromCLSID(clsid, &tmpbuf);
        CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); // инициализация COM для ридеров
    hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IDispatch, (void **)&pWApp);
    hr = pWApp->QueryInterface(__uuidof(mifare::IMifareDrv), (void **)&pMiDrv);
    pMiDrv->PortNumber = 4;
    pMiDrv->Connect();
    pMiDrv->BeepTone = 1;
    pMiDrv->PcdBeep();
}
    return 0;
}
```

И вот ответ под Qt

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QAxWidget>
QAxWidget *drvFR;
#define CLSID_DrvFR "{450E3DC0-5370-4007-BD5F-90827EC2C2D6}" // это GUID для     объекта драйвера (у меня он звался Addin.MifareDrv). GUID вытащил из регистра 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
drvFR = new QAxWidget();
drvFR->setControl(CLSID_DrvFR);
drvFR->dynamicCall("FindDevice()");
drvFR->dynamicCall("Connect()");
drvFR->setProperty("BeepTone", 1);
drvFR->dynamicCall("PcdBeep()");
....
и дописать в .pro write QT += axcontainer.
```

Comment: покажите текст ошибки

Comment: @psy_duck Ваш последний апдейт является ответом поэтому его не нужно в вопросе писать, он должен быть отдельным ответом. РУСО не форум! Пожалуйста почитаете [справку](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по примеру для "Делфи" `MifareDrv.dll` является библиотекой COM. Вы же в примере с `QLibrary` пытаетесь ее использовать как обычную "плоскую" DLL, что не совсем правильно. Чтобы использовать `MifareDrv.dll` нужно использовать базовые инструменты для `COM` из "Вижуал Студио".

В общем, проще код показать. Вот ваш пример для "Делфи" переведенный на Си++ "Вижуал Студио":

```cpp
// Если не жмет, можно абсолютный путь указать.
// Переименование пространства имен бибилотеки MifareDrv делается
// для того, чтобы точно знать кокое у этого простарнства будет имя
#import "MifareDrv.dll" rename_namespace("mifare") 

CLSID driver_clsid;
if(SUCCEEDED(CLSIDFromProgID(__T("AddIn.MifareDrv"), &driver_clsid))
{
    mifare::IMifareDrvPtr driver;
    if(SUCCEEDED(driver.CreateInstance(driver_clsid))
    {
        driver->Beep();
    }
}
```

Директива [#import](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx) является специфической для Си++ из "Визуал Студио", она выполняет следующее:

1. Загружает файл описания библиотеки *.tlb из указанного места, в данном примере импортируется DLL и файл *.tlb содержится в ней как ресурс
2. На основе полученного файла *.tlb генерирует заголовочный файл Си++ с именем `<имя библиотеки>.tlh` и файл обверток с именем `<имя библиотеки>.tli`
3. Кроме прочего, в файле *.tlh для каждого найденного в библиотеке интерфейса генерируется обявление умного указателя [_com_ptr_t](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/417w8b3b.aspx) с именем `<имя интерфейса>Ptr`. В примере это `IMifareDrvPtr`.

Отдельно отмечу, что приведенный пример может не компилироватся по причине того, что в библиотеке `MifareDrv.dll` может не быть интерфейса `IMifareDrv`. Чтобы узнать его точное имя нужно во-первых прочитать документацию к библиотеке, во-вторых внимательно изучить содержание сгенерированного заголовочника `MifareDrv.tlh`.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую как вы сказали.

Comment: Так, пробую. В общем, да, ругается на Imifare. У меня вот вопрос, а проще варианта нет? Просто по-моему вот все вот в таком же духе 
http://lavrsoft.ru/caslp/caslpdll.htm У меня имя объекта AddIn.MifareDrv

Comment: @psy_duck Добавил создание объекта по имени. Проще не получится вам в любом случае нужно знать точный интерфейс, либо использовать [IDispatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221608(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: В общем, докинул рабочую версию под Visual C++. Там очень важно было CoInitializeEx для устройства. 
Спасибо вам за правильное направление.

Comment: @psy_duck По вашему решению. Рекомендую всетаки использовать умные указатели _com_ptr_t, а не голые указатели, и еще промежуточный IDispatch совершенно лишний.

Answer (score -1):

Я бы предложил загружать библиотеку через LoadLibrary и получать адреса функций с помощью GetProcAddress